# HTML auto create list view

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web designing.

I am trying to create a website, with a list view of dates.
I have found some code on how to create this list.
But when I try to create it automatically, the list does not open.
I would appreciate it if someone can give me some advise.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/cdn/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/cdn/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ninotree.css" />
<script src="ninotree.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -1.3em;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="butt1" onclick="MakeMonths()">Make More</button>
<button id="butt2" onclick="MakeDays()">Make More2</button>

<ul class="tree">
  <li><a href="#">2020</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">January</a>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Monday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Tuesday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Wednesday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Thursday<br></li>
             <div id="AddCHK1"></div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li><a href="#">Feb</a>
        <ul>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Monday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Tuesday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Wednesday<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">Thursday<br></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

          <div id="Addmonth"></div>
            
          <li><a href="#">DEC</a>
          <ul>
                   <div id="AddCHK2"></div>
          </ul>
          </li>
                
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>

<script>
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

function onlyOne(checkbox) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
        if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false
    })
}

function MakeMonths()
{
    var data=['MAR','APR'];
    var output="";
    var dataList;
        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
    {   
        dataList=data[i];
            output+= '<li><a href="#">'+dataList+'</a><ul> <div id="AddCHK1"></div>   </ul></li>';
        document.getElementById("Addmonth").innerHTML=output;
    }
}

function MakeDays()
{
    var data=['Fri','Sat'];
    var output="";
    var dataList;
        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
    {   
        dataList=data[i];
            output+= '<li><input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">'+dataList+'<br></li>';
        document.getElementById("AddCHK1").innerHTML=output;
        document.getElementById("AddCHK2").innerHTML=output;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If there is maybe another way to make a list of dates, that can be selected to use for reporting, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fyi, `<div>` is not valid inside `<ul>`

Comment: Why don't you use radio's if only one option may be selected? It's not good to change the default UX for users